# Accessing null-terminated character

Tags: c, arrays, null-terminated

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour).

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char arr[] = "Hello";
   char *ptr = arr + 5;
   printf("%s\n",ptr);
}
```

In the above code, I have accessed null-terminated character.

So, What actually happens when accessing null terminated character in literal string? Is it Undefined behaviour?

Comment: By "accessing" you mean reading?  Why would the null character be any different to any other character in the string?  If you tried to write, went *beyond* the bounds of the string, then the effect is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you're passing an empty *string* as the argument, so it should be treated as such.

For `%s` conversion specifier, with `printf()` family

> [...]Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.[...]

In your case, the null terminator happens to appear at the first element in the *array*, that's it.

Just for clarification, accessing a null-terminator is OK, accessing a `NULL` pointer is not OK, and they both are different things!!

Answer (score 4):

You are basically still accessing a null-terminated string.
It is just zero characters long, i.e. it does not contain anything to print.

Your code is basically the same as

```
 printf("");
```

Compare this, not duplicate but similar question:

[Effect of "+1" after the format string parameter to printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50729625/effect-of-1-after-the-format-string-parameter-to-printf/50729679#50729679)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing particular. A pointer to the null character is interpreted as a zero-length string by functions that expect a string.